# MQTT Single Client vs Multiple Client

Tags: java, mqtt, iot, mosquitto, paho

Right now, we are designing and MQTT based application which deals with iot devices.

We have the main device which connect with all other IOT devices. and any message publishes from the main device will receive by MQTT client app. 
We have multiple main devices,

my question is do I need to create multiple MQTT clients each per the main device of a single client for all main devices.

if I go with a single client then if it fails, it will reconnect but facing a loss of data.

suppose if I go with multiple clients, then if it fails it only affect on one main device but  I am afraid that multiple client may consume lots of memory. when a number of main devices growing will take a lot of memory. also, need to maintained (prevent) client from being garbage collected.

any recommendations and any advice on this.

Comment: Where does the MQTT server reside?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail where these clients will be running. It sounds like you are planning on running a client for each device on the backend?

Comment: @Uhs MQTT Broker will be a separate server which takes and give a message to other clients, java MQTT client will connect with microservice and put data in to database

Comment: @hardillb basically it will be one microservice which create java mqtt client per user.